# Extracting a property from an array of an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object

I've got an object, containing an array of objects, containing an array of values:

```
stdClass Object (
    [devices] => Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [location] => 1
        [delegate] => 
        [type] => 1 
        [id] => 1234 
        [IP] => 1.2.3.4
        [name] => host1
        [owner] => user6 
        [security] => 15
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [location] => 2
        [delegate] => 
        [type] => 1 
        [id] => 4321 
        [IP] => 4.3.2.1
        [name] => host2
        [owner] => user9 
        [security] => 15
        )
    )
)
```

I want to extract just the id and name into an array in the form of:
$devices['id'] = $name;

I considered using the `array_map()` function, but couldn't work out how to use it... Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use a function which accepts the object and returns your array then call it: `$devices = myfunction($my_object);`

Comment: May seem trivial but that structure dont make no sense man

Comment: Show us a `print_r($top_object)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will generate you a new array like I think you want

I know you says that `delegate` is an object but the print does not show it that way

```
$new = array();
foreach($obj->devices as $device) {
    $new[][$device->id] = $device->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this not work? Untested but it cycles through the object structure to extract what I think you need.

```
$devices = myfunction($my_object);

function myfunction($ob){
    $devices = array();
    if(isset($ob->devices)){
        foreach($ob->devices as $d){
            if(isset($d->delegate->name && isset($d->delegate->id))){
                $devices[$d->delegate->id] = $d->delegate->name;
            }
        }
    }
    return($devices);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im usually using this function to generate all child and parent array stdclass / object, but still make key same :

```
function GenNewArr($arr=array()){
    $newarr = array();
    foreach($arr as $a=>$b){
        $newarr[$a] = is_object($b) || is_array($b) ? GenNewArr($b) : $b ;
    }
    return $newarr;
}
```